# Updating expired certificate at tomcat, without removing the old one

Tags: java, tomcat

I want my tomcat server to serve more than one certificate; the old certificate is about to expire, and i want to update it without denying the service for clients didn't update it yet, giving them a change to switch to new one. I have a connector configuration like this

```
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8080" acceptCount="100" maxConnections="400" maxThreads="2000" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="keystore.p12" keystorePass="****"  keyAlias="alias_new"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Is there any why i can change the configuration to server both certificate (both 'alias_new' & 'alias_old')?

I tried adding two private key entries to my keystore, and removing alias field from connector, but it always picks up one of them and all clients validating the other one are declined.

Comment: No SSL/TLS server of any kind can do that, not tomcat and not any other, because the protocol doesn't allow it -- unless you also change the domain name (and the clients use SNI, which pretty much all now do). If you can't use 'real' certs from one or more standardly-trusted CA(s), the safe method is to set all clients to accept _both_ old and new, then change server to use new, then if you want and when convenient change clients to not accept old.

Comment: Many thanks Dear for your valuable comment, will read more about SNI usage